# How can I Paginate Firestore Data in ListView.Builder and Still Get Realtime Updates in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I can't figure out how to paginate Firestore data without breaking the realtime listener. The data is passed to a StreamBuilder and displayed in a ListView.builder. I'm trying to fetch the next set of data when the user reaches maxScrollExtent.

I understand how to to use startAfter and limit with Firestore to paginate. If I pass the fetched data to a StreamController and use that in the StreamBuilder, pagination works fine but Firestore doesn't send any updates to the device.

If I pass Firestore.instance.(...).snapshots() directly to the StreamBuilder (without using a StreamController), then I get updates from the server, but pagination is all screwed up. The UI is rebuilt and I'm sent to the top of the list.

Using StreamController

```
final int limit = 2;
final _list = List<DocumentSnapshot>();
final _listController = StreamController<List<DocumentSnapshot>>.broadcast();
DateTime startAt;
bool _isAllDataFetched = false;

Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> get listStream => _listController.stream;

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _eventDao
        ?.getAllEventMedia(event?.id ?? "",
            startAfter: startAt?.millisecondsSinceEpoch, limit: limit)
        ?.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      _list.addAll(querySnapshot.documents);
      _listController.sink.add(_list);
    })?.catchError((error) {
      print(error);
    });
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
      stream: listStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return ErrorPage(imageAsset: AssetResources.failed);
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            snapshot.data.isNotEmpty &&
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          startAt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            snapshot.data.last.data[EventMediaSchema.creationDate],
          );
          return MediaDisplayManagerAlt(
            documents: snapshot.data,
            atBottom: _fetchNextDocumentSet,
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          _isAllDataFetched = true;
        }

        return Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text("NO MEDIA YET"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );

void _fetchNextDocumentSet() async {
    if (!_isAllDataFetched) {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _eventDao?.getAllEventMedia(event?.id ?? "",
          startAfter: startAt?.millisecondsSinceEpoch, limit: limit);
      _list.addAll(querySnapshot.documents);
      _listController.sink.add(_list);
    }
  }
```

Passing snapshots to StreamBuilder

```
final int limit = 2;
DateTime startAt;
bool _isAllDataFetched = false;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _eventDao?.(event?.id ?? "",
            startAfter: startAt?.millisecondsSinceEpoch, limit: limit),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return ErrorPage(imageAsset: AssetResources.failed);
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.documents.isNotEmpty) {
          return MediaDisplayManagerAlt(
            documents: snapshot.data.documents,
            atBottom: _fetchNextDocumentSet,
          );
        }

        return Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text("NO MEDIA YET"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

void _fetchNextDocumentSet() async {
    if (!_isAllDataFetched) {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _eventDao?.getAllEventMedia(event?.id ?? "",
          startAfter: startAt?.millisecondsSinceEpoch, limit: limit);
      _list.addAll(querySnapshot.documents);
      _listController.sink.add(_list);
    }
  }
```

It seems like these two approaches need to be combined in some way to get the desired effect, but after two days of trying I can't figure how to do that.

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? Dealing with a similar challenge myself

Comment: Unfortunately not. I gave up up on it. Looking back, it could be that data needs to be cached locally so the widget tree isn't rebuilt. I had to do that in some other places to solve a different problem, but I didn't try it in regards to pagination. Good luck.